# session shows null when it uses SlingRepository service, why?

Tags: adobe, aem, jackrabbit, jcr, sling

I made one bundle, that deploys in OSGI container and now in active state, and provides some services.

And I have another bundle that uses these services and one more service i.e., **SlingRepository**, to get admin prevelage to make nodes in Apache Jachrabbit.

Second bundle is just to use the implementation that is written in first bundle.

For that, I code to run the first bundle in Activate annotation of Second bundle.
But when I deploy second bundle , it shows `Null` for session.

```
@Reference
session = repository.loginadministrataive(null);
```

Then , I try another method , in which I make one class in first bundle instead to make another for that,  i.e., Activator class that implements BundleActivator interface. But that shows same problem.

Can you tell me how can I solve this problem ?

Can you tell me how can I run first bundle using second bundle ?

Thanks in advance. Lookig for your kind reply.

Answer (score 4):

@Reference on such a line of code is wrong, have a look at Sling examples for more info.

The [Slingbucks sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/slingbucks/), for example uses @Reference to get a SlingRepository, you could use that as a starting point.

Also, you probably don't need an Activator for that, declarative services annotations should be enough, you'll see that in the sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved this problem. I also posted the complete answer with some code. Thanks again :) Now I stuck in another problem in which it I put some code in Activate annotation of second bundle, and the task is to crawl whole website. Now I wanted to stop this in the middle , but it does not stop. Can you tell me how can I stop this ?

Comment: You shouldn't add long-running code in an activate method, but rather setup what your component needs and start a thread that does the work. There's a number of examples in the Sling codebase, if you look for code that contains Activate and Thread you should find them.

Comment: Can you please give me the link. So that I can implement in my code, please.

Comment: I found my error, actually I made new Class for a thread and create new object for running thread. Thats why it has null value in all the variables, and creates problem. All the things are solved now.